# Formal way to say "as many times as he wishes"

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote this sentence

> Student is able to listen a word **as many times as he wishes**

Are there more formal ways, or other alternatives to say that?

Answer (score 2):

It's okay as it is, except that *listen a word* should be *listen **to** a word*.

However, unless you are describing a system that is only for male students, the practice of using *he* to refer to a person of unknown gender is becoming obsolete, and may strike some readers as sexist.  You may wish to write:

> A student may listen to a word as many times as he or she wishes.

Or rephrase to use the plural:

> Students may listen to words as many times as they wish.

Or rephrase completely:

> A student may listen to a word an unlimited number of times.

Comment: Also, I note that you have corrected "is able to" to "may". You might want to explain the distinction.